# how do you nest index match and concat in a formula from a data set?

Tags: excel-formula

Trying to get all the values in a cell to display horizontally.

I can do index and match but whenever I try to put concat in, it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you mean =TRANSPOSE() ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.